# Run shell script with sudo from PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I currently have a PHP file on my ubuntu box that i want to use to create users on the machine from a web interface (security blablabla, its all on an internal network completely inaccessible from anyone who would accidentally/purposefully cause harm to the system) I initially tried using this:

```
    shell_exec("sudo mkdir -m 755 ".escapeshellarg($directory));

    shell_exec("sudo useradd -s /bin/false -d ".escapeshellarg($directory)." -p ".crypt($pass,$salt)." ".escapeshellarg($servername));
```

but obviously this exposes both mkdir and useradd to be passwordless sudo'd, so instead of doing this i decided to reduce complications by create a shell script in /etc called 'newserver.sh', now in that i have this;

```
#!/bin/bash
#Var 1 = Directory, Var 2 = Username Var 3 = Password
mkdir "$1"
chmod 755 "$1"
useradd -s /bin/false -d "$1" -p "$3" "$2"
chown "$2" "$1"
```

which seemed to work abit better, and works pretty fine when i run it it from terminal, but when the PHP exexutes it using

```
shell_exec("sudo sh /etc/newserver.sh /home/testuser testuser testpass");
```

it doesnt seem to do anything (ive even tested with the same parameters as when i run it from the terminal.

FYI my sudoers file has this line in it `www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /etc/newserver.sh`

Comment: As per [the docs for shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec): "it is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required". You're simply ASSUMING everything's working fine with your code. Never do that. Assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise. Switch to exec(), and start checking for output/return values.

Comment: returns nothing, could it be the fact sh isnt sudoable? its no asking me for a password when i run the command myself though so im unsure...

Comment: Also, Apache usually runs under `www-data` user and group and you will not have access to `sudo` commands like `useradd` from php. it might work with `bash -c` under a sudo user. I have never tried it.

Comment: Look at the FYI and the bottom of the question, i already said that www-data is in the sudoers file for not need a password for /etc/newserver.sh. I previously has it as /usr/adduser instead and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the password must be cryptographed, like this:

```
/etc/newserver.sh /home/testuser testuser "$6$VP9.GI9D$nVjpXIlgoTCLYICNW9ijPqg07opPrjTU2ilYULaT4rut8S9CAmWggMXuOhJ27C5ltwCRfzSxEVgSlReA2i/rH1"
```

And I think, you should use "-c" as argument.

```
shell_exec("sudo sh -c \"/etc/newserver.sh /home/testuser testuser testpass\"");
```

Comment: I know about the cryptographic passwords, the command should still run and the account should still be valid apart from not being able to access it through its password, im using this as nothing but a test bed, i have a different set of parameters to be passed from the PHP including a encrypted password. ill try using -c now.

Comment: That responds that permission is denied.

Comment: You checked the permission of execution of file?
chmod u+x /etc/newserver.sh

Comment: Executing in a web environment does not provide a standard input stream to requests (HTTP data being not-included of course). `sudo` naturally prompts for a password, which you fail to provide 3 times automatically : permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Running as root can be done in two ways :

- Using `sudo` (making `www-data` a sudoer is nothing like a good idea...)
- Setting a setuid

Take a look a `/bin/ping` :

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root /bin/ping
```

It belongs to root, but the 's' replacing the 'x' (execute) means that this program is setuid : it'll always be executed with the owner's identity : root. `ping` is a program that needs to build ICMP packets, and only root can manipulate those until the end.

You can create a similar environement : place your commands in a shell script (let's say `myscript.sh`) and :

```
chown root:root myscript.sh # Give it to root.
chmod u+s myscript.sh # Use setuid on it.
```

Now, when you run it, even as a regular user (or `www-data` for the web server...), the processes will be created under root's identity.

**Danger** Giving setuid (as root) to a script is very dangerous. You should be careful with permissions : don't allow anyone but people you're interested in to run it. For instance, create a group called *myscriptexec* for people allowed to run this script :

```
addgroup myscriptexec
chgrp myscriptexec myscript.sh
chmod g+x # Group can execute.
chmod o= myscript.sh # No one executes except root and group members.
```

Then, add users to this group, as you need.

If you need to check your script, I'd suggest you use a temporary log file, for debugging purposes :

```
exec > /tmp/mylog.log
exec 2> /tmp/mylog.log
```

Comment: When i did that, and then try and run the sh without sudo it fails because its not run as root - or should i say, it responds with errors on the mkdir and adduser because theyre not run as root.

Comment: My bad : commands executed after are not run as root. Try prefixing commands with `sudo` inside your script, you should not be asked for a password (the "parent" program is run as root).

Comment: alright so now i have `$test = exec("sh /etc/newserver.sh ".escapeshellarg($directory)." ".escapeshellarg($servername)." ".crypt($pass,$salt)." > /home/nodeadmin/test.log");
        echo $test;`
it doesnt echo anything and it doesnt create that file. im at an end as to what to do now.

Comment: Your redirection `> /home/[...]` should be made in the shell script file. At the beginning, use : `exec > /tmp/mylog ; exec 2> /tmp/mylog` ^^